# Is there an intuitive way to understand how this Javascript callback function is working?

Tags: javascript, callback, tree, binary

Code line in question:

```
callbackFn ? callbackFn(currentNode) : levelOrderList.push(currentNode.value);
```

I am having trouble of a way to think of this in psuedo-code terms since 'callbackFn' is used like a function but not defined like a function.

I know this code works and have ran it myself. I have also solved this without using the callbackFn, but I would really like to understand why this works.

My guess for psuedo cod would be:
if callbackFn exists (not null or undefined), then return callbackFn(currentNode).
else push currentNode.value to the levelOrderList.

Full code for context:

```
  function levelOrder(callbackFn) {
    const queue = [this.root];
    const levelOrderList = [];
    while (queue.length > 0) {
      const currentNode = queue.shift();
      callbackFn ? callbackFn(currentNode) : levelOrderList.push(currentNode.value);

      const enqueueList = [
        currentNode?.leftChild,
        currentNode?.rightChild
      ].filter((value) => value);
      queue.push(...enqueueList);
    }
    if (levelOrderList.length > 0) return levelOrderList;
  }
```

Comment: Whoever wrote that would have done themselves and future readers like you a service by not trying to golf the `if` down to the conditional operator. Better version: `if (callbackFn) { callbackFn(currentNode); } else { levelOrderList.push(currentNode.value); }`. Wish they had used [`no-unused-expressions`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions)

Comment: What do you mean by "not defined like a function"? It's a parameter, it will be define in the caller. That's what a callback is -- it's a function provided by the caller, which this function calls when necessary. An example you might be familiar with is `Array.map()` -- you provide it a callback function to call on each element of the array.

Comment: Your pseudo-code is correct.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It looks like the original writer intended it to be returned at the end of the while-loop, but only if the list length is not zero. Looks kinda funky if you compare it to a recursive base case or guard clauses but I think it's okay in this instance.

Comment: No, the expression is completely unused, regardless of where you are in the loop - better for it to be `if`/`else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess for pseudo code is correct.

The author of that could should better have used an `if...else` structure like your pseudo code does. The conditional operator (`? :`) is used here as an unnecessary short-cut. Normally you would use the conditional operator to *use* the value that it evaluates to, like `x = condition ? a : b;`. But here that value is ignored. There is really no good reason to avoid `if...else` here.

The author added support for a callback mechanism as an alternative to returning an array. This doesn't look like best practice to me either. For two reasons:

- This "polymorphism" can be confusing for the user of such an API. It is easier to understand when the two functionalities are offered by two different functions, one that returns the result in an array, another that calls the callback. The caller will choose the function based on how they want to deal with the traversed nodes.
- A callback mechanism is rather "old style". It makes more sense to turn this function into a generator function. The caller can then easily decide what to do with the nodes that the returned iterator yields: collect those nodes in an array or just process them one by one.

This is how that generator function would look like:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.leftChild = this.rightChild = null;
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.root = null;
        for (let value of values) this.add(value);
    }
    add(value) {
        function addTo(node) {
            if (!node) return new Node(value);
            if (value < node.value) {
                node.leftChild = addTo(node.leftChild);
            } else {
                node.rightChild = addTo(node.rightChild);
            }
            return node;
        }
        this.root = addTo(this.root);
    }
    *levelOrder() {
        if (!this.root) return;
        const queue = [this.root];
        while (queue.length > 0) {
            const currentNode = queue.shift();
            yield currentNode.value;
            if (currentNode.leftChild) queue.push(currentNode.leftChild);
            if (currentNode.rightChild) queue.push(currentNode.rightChild);
        }
    }
}

// Demo
const tree = new Tree(4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 3);
// Several ways to use the levelOrder generator function:
console.log(...tree.levelOrder());
console.log(Array.from(tree.levelOrder()));
for (let value of tree.levelOrder()) console.log(value);
```

Comment: That's similar to how I ended up writing the code for level order because it was more intuitive to do so. The project had asked for a callback implementation so that might be why the author wrote it like that. Thanks for confirming and adding your insights!